# Is there a way to import Redshift Connection in PySpark AWS Glue Job?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

There is an option to add DB connections under Advanced Network Connections in Job Details. Is there an approach to import this connection directly in to the code. I have to hardcode the connection credentials or use secrets. I am trying to see if I can directly import the connection details directly into my code.